# Why is my object in blender bigger by approximately a factor 10 than in my CAD program?

Tags: import, units

I export my CAD models, which I create on [Creo](http://www.ptc.com/product/creo/) 2.0 (originally called Wildfire 5.0) as `STL` files, and import them into blender.

But when I compare their sizes, the objects shown in blender are usually bigger than the objects shown on my CAD program by approximately a factor 10.

Did blender confuses the unit? Because when I exported the object as an `STL` file, it didn't give me an option to set the unit. Is there a default unit for STL files?

The units I usually work with on Creo 2.0 are `mm`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Blender's default unit system is `None`, so it uses its own "Blender Units" (BU). But if you switch it to `Metric` in the *Scene* tab (*Properties Editor*), you'll notice that nothing changed. And **1 BU** will now be **1m**.

With `Metric` enabled, there will be a property available called scene *Scale*. You can set it to `0.1` to correct the scaling problem (granted, it's really 1:10). But I worry not all exporters will respect it.

So it might be better so *Select All* objects (<kbd>A</kbd>) and scale everything down (<kbd>S</kbd>, type `0.1`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>). Make sure the scaling center is the scene origin `(0,0,0)`, e.g. reset the *3D Cursor* (<kbd>N</kbd>-sidebar, right-click on one of the 3 value fields and click *Reset All to Default Values*, or press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>) and use it as *Pivot Point* (press <kbd>.</kbd>).

Comment: Thank you, I did reconsider the scaling option, but I just want to know why it converts **mm** (it's original unit) to **m** when it is imported into blender as a STL file

Comment: Seems like there is no unit system specified in STL, but either or both, Credo and Blender may do some conversion or make assumptions about the scaling. The factor 1:10 is weird though, maybe 1 unit = 1mm in Credo export, but Blender imports 1 unit as 1cm (1:10)? "4) Generally STL file has no UNITS attached to it so its always good practice to send overall part sizes along with your STL file" ([source](http://www.arptech.com.au/stlspecs.htm))